# Converting .glb file with animation to .reality file and add interaction to play animation

Tags: realitykit, reality-composer, usdz

I've got a web app to display and interact with animated glb files in the browser and an AR view button that points to the same model as a usdz file (which is converted from the glb file with USDZTools using usdz converter) to display it in ARQuickLook on iPhone.
Since there is RealityKit and reality files now, i've been wondering whether there is a way to export the animated glb file to a reality file and add some interaction (like tap on display or model) to start and stop, or play further animations.
Usdz converter only provides auto loop animation.
The goal would be to create some interactive reality files as shown from apples [quick look examples](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/) on the base of an animated glb file.

As I mentioned I tried converting the glb file with usdz converter which works fine, but usdz files do not support playing animations on user interaction. So I tried to add interaction with reality composer and export the project to a reality file, but I want them somehow to be added in the converting process without using reality composer.